# irreducible character $X(g)=|fix(g)|-1$

Tags: group-theory

Let $n$ be an arbitrary natural number and $X$ be the irreducible character $X(g)=|fix(g)|-1$ in $S_n$. 
Whether there is a way in general to show $X\in X^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably $X \in X^2$ means that $X$ is a component of the character $X^2$?

Let $S_n$ act on $\Omega = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Then (for $n \ge 2$), the number of orbits of $S_n$ on $\Omega$, $\Omega^2$ and $\Omega^3$ is 1,2 and 5, respectively.

Hence, writing $F(g)$ for $|{\rm Fix}(G)|$, we have

$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} F(g) = 1$,      $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} F(g)^2 = 2$,        $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}F(g)^3 = 5$,

and the number of times that $X$ is a component of $X^2$ is

$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}X(g)^3 = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}(F(g)-1)^3 = 1$.